# Resroring deleted posts

Tags: facebook

I had posted some comments to Facebook by using 3rd party posting tool which is connected to apps

When I have deleted the apps from the facebook account because of tool change, all the past posts via the apps were also deleted.

I didn't want to delete these posts.
Is it possible to restore the deleted comments somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get these back, as FB does not support this.
You removed the apps to post those items, so they were removed.